# The divergence as flux density

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

> Let $S_\epsilon$ be the sphere with center in $(0,0,0)$ and radius $\epsilon$, and the vectorfield $F(x,y,z) = (yx^2, xyz, x^2y^2)$. Let $\hat{N}$ be the unit-normal vector for $S_\epsilon$ pointing outwards. Evalute the limit 
>   $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \frac{3}{4\pi\epsilon^3}\oint_{S_\epsilon} F \cdot\hat{N}dS$$

I've swapped the original vectorfield in the task with a random one just to clarify if I understand this correctly. I read about this limit in my calculus book which was simply defined as the divergence (as flux density) **div F**. Does evaluating this limit mean to simply find the divergence, which is very easy for my vectorfield; **div F** $= x(2y+z)$. Or have i misunderstood the meaning of this limit and how it correlates to divergence itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually one defines $\mathrm{div}F:=\partial_x F_1 + \partial_y F_2 +\partial_z F_3$ and then proves the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem):
$$
\iiint_{B_\epsilon} \mathrm{div} F ~\mathrm{d}V = \iint_{S_\epsilon}  F \cdot N~\mathrm{d}S.
$$
The left intergal is taken over a ball with center $0$ and  radius $\epsilon$, thus its volume is $V(B_\epsilon)= 4\pi\epsilon^3/3$. Consequently
$$
\frac{3}{4 \pi \epsilon^3}\iint_{S_\epsilon}  F \cdot N~\mathrm{d}S = \frac 1{V(B_\epsilon)}\iiint_{B_\epsilon} \mathrm{div} F ~\mathrm{d}V.
$$
Now the right hand side is the average value of the function $\mathrm{div}F$ over the ball $B_\epsilon$. Provided $F$ is reasonably nice (continously differentiable would be enough), these avarages then tend to $\mathrm{div}F(0,0,0)$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that by the divergence theorem,
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \frac{3}{4\pi\epsilon^3}\oint_{S_\epsilon(x,y,z)} F \cdot\hat{N}dS=\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial z}$$
However, which side of that equation is the definition of the divergence depends on the text.  It sounds like you are given the left-hand side for the definition.  This means you can't just substitute the right-hand side unless the theorem is already proved.

Since the question is asking about a specific point, it could be that you are expected to explicitly calculate the integral on the left-hand side and verify that the indicated limit is $0$ (that is, $x(2y+z)$ when $x=y=z=0$).